# R generating a sparse matrix

Tags: r, data.table, sparse-matrix, reshape2

I have a large file with the following format which I read as `x`

```
userid,productid,freq
293994,8,3
293994,5,3
949859,2,1
949859,1,1
123234,1,1
123234,3,1
123234,4,1
...
```

It gives the product a given user bought and its frequency. I'm trying to make it into a matrix which gives all the productid's as columns and userids as rows with the frequency value as the entry. So the expected output is

```
       1 2 3 4 5 8
293994 0 0 0 0 3 3
949859 1 1 0 0 0 0
123234 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

It is a sparse matrix. I tried doing `table(x[[1]],x[[2]])` which works for small files, but beyond a point `table` gives an error

```
Error in table(x[[1]], x[[2]]) : 
 attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
Execution halted
```

Is there a way to get this to work? I'm on R-3.1.0 and its supposed to support 2^51 sized vectors, so confused why it can't handle the file size. I've 40MM lines with total file size of 741M. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want real sparse matrices then look in the "Matrix" package.

Comment: Did you try `aggregate(freq ~ userid + productid,data = df,sum)`?

Comment: or perhaps `library(tidyr); spread(x,productid,freq,fill = 0)`

Comment: Been trying `aggregate` but its very slow.

Comment: Aggregate does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

One `data.table` way of doing it is:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

# adjust fun.aggregate as necessary - not very clear what you want from OP
dcast.data.table(your_data_table, userid ~ productid, fill = 0L)
```

You can check if that works for your data.

Comment: I get the following error `Error in dcast.data.table(x, deviceid ~ cxbrandid, fun = sum, fill = 0L) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:137
In addition: Warning message:
In setattr(l, "row.names", .set_row_names(length(l[[1L]]))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: @broccoli perhaps you can a `dput` sample of your data - it works for the data in OP

Comment: The method works for small data sets, but at scales I mention in the question it gives the error message I have shown above.

Comment: @broccoli perhaps aggregating **before** you `dcast` would help? i.e. do `dcast.data.table(dt[, sum(freq), by = list(userid, productid)], userid ~ productid, fill = 0L)`

Comment: Nope doesn't work. The problem "long vectors not supported yet: " strikes me as weird because I'm on R 3.1.0 which is supposed to support long vectors up to 2^51 or something. Right?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm sure @Arun does :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#This is old, but worth noting the Matrix package sparseMatrix() to directly format object without reshaping.

    userid <- c(293994,293994,949859,949859,123234,123234,123234)
    productid <- c(8,5,2,1,1,3,4)
    freq <- c(3,3,1,1,1,1,1)

    library(Matrix)

#The dgCMatrix sparseMatrix is a fraction of the size and builds much faster than reshapeing if the data gets large

    x <- sparseMatrix(i=as.integer(as.factor(userid)),
                      j=as.integer(as.factor(productid)),
                      dimnames = list(as.character(levels(as.factor(userid))),
                                   as.character(levels(as.factor(productid)))
                                   ),
                      x=freq)


#Easily converted to a matrix.
    x <- as.matrix(x)

#Learned this the hard way using recommenderlab (package built on top of Matrix) to build a binary matrix, so in case it helps someone else.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyr approach to this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

# Replicate your example data
example_data <- matrix(
  c(293994,8,3,
    293994,5,3,
    949859,2,1,
    949859,1,1,
    123234,1,1,
    123234,3,1,
    123234,4,1),
  ncol = 3,
  byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  set_colnames(c('userid','productid','freq'))

# Convert data into wide format
spread(example_data, key = productid, value = freq, fill = 0)
```

`spread` will be a lot faster than the base R `table` operation, but at scale, `data.table` would in turn easily outperform `tidyr` / `dplyr`. However, as noted in the previous answer, the data.table equivalent `dcast` isn't working properly. This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1691) which, unfortunately, remains unresolved.

I tried the `tidyr` approach at scale (2 mio records). I couldn't make it work on my local machine. So you'll have to either chop it up (then using `rbind`) or take it to a cluster (with `rhadoop` or `sparklyr`).

Nonetheless, code for a reproducible "big data" example below in case somebody else would like to add something.

```
# Make some random IDs
randomkey <- function(digits){
  paste(sample(LETTERS, digits, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
}

products <- replicate(10, randomkey(20)) %>% unique
customers <- replicate(500000, randomkey(50)) %>% unique

big_example_data <- data.frame(
  useruid = rep(sample(customers, length(customers), replace = FALSE), 4),
  productid = sample(products, replace = TRUE),
  freq = sample(1:5)
)
# 2 mio rows of purchases
dim(big_example_data)
# With useruid, productid, freq
head(big_example_data)

# Test tidyr approach
system.time(
  big_matrix <- spread(big_example_data, key = productid, value = freq, fill = 0)
)
```